# Object Layer for a Java RPG

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a basic RPG in java.  I think I have a good hold of the basics of java, but when it comes to this stuff I'm definitely a beginner.  Anyway, I thought that it would be best to create a map with two layers: a terrain layer with water, rocks, grass, etc... and an object layer with trees, houses, items- things that the player can interact with. So far I have a terrain layer, produced using a 2-Dim array.  My question is: how can I make an object layer, more specifically, how can I make a layer that contains objects whose coordinates can be interacted with?

Below is what I have so far. I apologize, my code must be organized strangely- like I said, I'm a beginner with this. Thanks for your time.

-Marcus

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage.*;
import java.io.File.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D.*;

public class mapStoreII extends JFrame implements KeyListener{


BufferedImage pic;
int width = 32;
int height = 32;
int px = 656;
int py = 656;

int[][] map_1 = {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,10,5,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,3,14,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,13,6,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},        
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,16,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,1,1,1}
        };

public mapStoreII(){
    setSize(875,750);
    setLocation(800,150);
    setTitle("Test_Organics_v.1");
    setResizable(true);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setVisible(true);   
}

public void paint(Graphics g){          
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    for(int y = 0; y<20; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x<24; x++){

            try {
            pic = ImageIO.read(new File(getImage(getMap(y,x))));            
            } catch (IOException e) {}

            graphics.drawImage(pic, (x*width)+50, (y*height)+50, null);                         
            graphics.setPaint(Color.red);
            graphics.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(px,py,32,32));       //Currently the player.
        }
    }
}

public int getMap(int y, int x){
    return map_1[y][x];
}

public String getImage(int a){
    if(a==2){
        return "shoreline_1.png";                           
    }
    else if(a==1){                      
        return "water_1.png";           
    }
    else if(a==9){
        return "player_on_dirt_1.png";
    }
    else if(a==3){
        return "island_left.png";
    }
    else if(a==4){
        return "island_right.png";
    }
    else if(a==5){
        return "island_up.png";
    }
    else if(a==6){
        return "island_down.png";
    }
    else if(a==7){
        return "chemical_1.png";
    }
    else if(a==10){
        return "island_topLC.png";
    }
    else if(a==11){
        return "island_topRC.png";
    }
    else if(a==12){
        return "island_botRC.png";
    }
    else if(a==13){
        return "island_botLC.png";
    }
    else if(a==14){
        return "island_center.png";
    }
    else if(a==15){
        return "shoreline_2.png";
    }
    else if(a==16){
        return "shoreline_3.png";
    }
    else{                                   
        return "grassydirt_1.png";          
    }
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event){ 
    int code = event.getKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            px-=8;
            repaint();                                                                          
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            px+=8;
            repaint();
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP || code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            py-=8;
            repaint();
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            py+=8;
            repaint();
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_I){         
            lineDraw inventory = new lineDraw();    //Opens an inventory.
        }
    }

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event){
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new mapStoreII();
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I may ask, what are you trying to accomplish by keeping the 2 layers separate? One would think that a natural complement of interacting with objects is to interact with the terrain as well. It would allow for a more extensible game design.

Perhaps create a model object called `Tile` to represent each grid and then have a boolean property on that class called `interactive`. That way you can easily change in the future whether soemthing is interactive. You could also conceivably use interfaces to determine if it serves an interactive role or use inheritance and have a TileClass

Another thing, you may want to extract your file creation to somewhere other than your `paint` method.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I actually did something similar to that.  A true/false state was applied to each tile in a separate array (which is unnecessary I know), but one problem I had was I don't know the best way to determine if my character is on a certain tile. In short, I'm having trouble connecting my player (the red circle) to the map.

Comment: You're right in that it is unnecessary - a dedicated MapTile class of some sort would be better. You could also add a property to deal with the "impassable" problem in your other comment. When a player hits "Left", check to make sure that the next tile over (if it exists) has the passable attribute set to `true`. For your character issue, you can always have the player's current X and Y stored and simply re-paint using the character image over the current tile.

Comment: OK I see what you are saying. The problem is that there really aren't "tiles," but just 32x32 pixel images.  Let's say my character moves 32 pixels at a time (although I have 8 in the above code); so I could check what the x and y coordinates of one move left are, but I have no way of assigning the "left tile" a boolean state, because again, there are no tile objects, just images. I hope I'm making sense here. Thanks again for the comment.

Comment: If your images are 32 pixels and your character moves 32 pixels, each of those is essentially 1 "unit" or "tile" as we've been calling it. It seems in my opinion that you're making things more complex for yourself by dealing in pixels instead of creating a class meant to hide those details. To immediately address your question, you may want to just google "2D collision detection" and see if that helps you out a bit. Also, you could consider using Swing's Layered Panes so you can draw your Character on a different pane than your terrain. Hopefully that helps a bit. =)

Comment: Thanks again. You made a good point there. What I've been looking for is actually collision detection.  I had read a little bit on it before, but for some reason didn't think to focus my searches on it. I'm still new. Good call!

Comment: Glad I could help. You may also want to check out the game developers stack exchange site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. You'll find a lot of specialized questions there, including 2D collision detection.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a great project! I had a lot of fun writing a Java RPG / roguelike game called [Tyrant](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tyrant/) a few years back. It's all open source so feel free to explore!

Some points you may find helpful:

- I had an object called Map ([Map.java source](http://tyrant.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tyrant/tyrant/mikera/engine/Map.java?view=markup))
- A Map stored both the tiles (in an int[] array) and objects (in a Thing[] array). I used one-dimensional arrays and calculated offsets into them using (x+y*mapWidth) but you can equally well use a 2 dimensional array
- Thing was a separate class that describes all the properties and behaviours of an object. It also contained a "next" pointer to another Thing, so that you could chain together a list of Things in a single square.
- It's a good idea to *separate* the graphics code from your game logic and game data structures. This helps keep your code maintainable and flexible - for example when you want to have store multiple maps that are not visible. In my case, I used a [MapPanel GUI component](http://tyrant.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tyrant/tyrant/mikera/tyrant/MapPanel.java?revision=1.43&view=markup) which extended JPanel and knew how to draw a Map, but the Map object itself contained no GUI or drawing related code.

Anyway hope this is helpful. Good luck!

Comment: This was helpful thanks! How did you determine if your player was interacting with objects or the map? For instance, my player moves around, but I can't think of a way to make a tile impassable.

Comment: Good question - Check out the function Map.isBlocked(x,y) - basically it checks first to see if the tile is passable, then checks to see if any objects in the square are of a "blocking" type. It returns true if the square is blocked, otherwise false if the square is passable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and for providing example code. My problem, I think, is that I don't know how to check a "tile."  In my code, I only have images. So a player is never really on a tile, but occupying coordinates on top of images.  Perhaps this is correct, but it probably isn't haha. In short, I don't know how to check the coordinates of my images to determine if I can move my player to them. For instance, let's say there's an impassable rock one "tile" to the left, how would I check that? Do I have to check the coordinates?  Thanks again, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: It's usually best to store the player's position as a map co-ordinate rather than a pixel co-ordinate. Then it is very easy to check your tile array! Then when drawing the player, you just need to multiply the map position of the player by the width of the tile to get the correct screen position. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Ok, I'm going to play around with that idea and try to figure something out. Thanks for your help!